# "tant de....que"?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, coordination

I saw this sentence on a brochure in Kyoto today (emphasis mine):

> Nijo, un château qui fut le témoin **tant de** la gloire et la chute des Tokugawa **que** des transitions de l'histoire du Japon.

I really am not at all sure how to interpret that. "Nijo, a castle which bore witness [something] the glory and the fall of Tokugawa [something] the transitions of the history of Japan."

How is *tant* being used here, and is it attached to the *de* or the *que* or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of "tant" here is "autant" or "tout autant" which means "equally". As a comparative term, "que" is attached" to it. [Copro's translation](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29740/12177) looks correct to me.

On the other hand, "de" is attached to "fut le témoin" ("être témoin de" means "witnessing").

Comment: AH HA! It was your last sentence which made it click for me. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could translate with "witness of the glory [..] as well as the transitions [...]".

"tant" carries here the idea of continuity and also an idea of accumulation of events.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to translate word for word into English, because it follows a structure *(“tant... que...” → “as much... as...”)* usually, but not in this case, easily translated as *“both A and B”*. Here, *A* itself is split into two distinct events, that is *the glory* and *the fall* of the Tokugawas, making the statement of *B*, the transitions in Japan’s history, appear a little redundant.

Something like the following, though it is not very elegant:

> Nijo, a castle that has been the witness of both the glory and the fall of the Tokugawas, and the transitions in the history of Japan.

Perhaps switching *“that has been the witness of”* to *“that has witnessed”* would be a little more native in English (?)...

The solution proposed by [copro](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29740/13100) is certainly a good option to make it more elegant, though it weakens the statement a bit, not putting so much emphasis on the extent of time and radical changes society went through during the existence of the castle:

> Nijo, a castle that has witnessed the glory and the fall of the Tokugawas, **as well** as the transitions in the history of Japan.